# Sony Vaio Sleep Mode

Tags: sleep, sony-vaio

I have a problem with the sleep mode on Sony Vaio F Series and Windows 7 x64. If I wake it up by opening the lid and pressing power button everything works fine.

However, if I wake it up on some other way (e.g. move the mouse), power light turns green and fan starts spinning, but LCD is dark and I cannot use keyboard (well, actually there is no sign that anyting works).

Only thing I can do is to reboot it by pressing power button.

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: What happens when you [disable the mouse from waking up your computer](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15132/stop-your-mouse-from-waking-up-your-windows-7-computer/)?

Comment: This works great, but it doesn't solve the real problem that I cannot wake it up correctly if the lid is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Installing newer version of Nvidia driver from their website solved the problem.